# Change password for a user on SQL Server using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Setup: SQL Server running in a AZURE enclave.  Mixed mode authentication.  SQL User is NOT a member of the admin group, just a basic user with read/write permissions to a database. I do not know what previous password is/was.  I have generated a new password.

I do not know what the password is for a sa level user.  I do not know if the technician running the script will have the correct permissions on the SQL Server either, as the roles are separated between windows and sql server administration are well defined. I do not know what the password is for the user in question could be at the moment the script is run.

**Using powershell, running as administrator (elevated) permissions - I would like to change the password for the sql user. How would I go about this?**

Comment: If you don't have access to an account that has permission to change password you can't; not in the way you want anyway... This has a very strong smell of an XY Problem.

Comment: Also, just being able to easily change the passwords of any account on an instance just with a local administrator account would, in my opinion, be a *huge* security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a sysadmin login, you'll have a Windows Administrator follow the procedure here: [Connect to SQL Server when system administrators are locked out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

This script will make the Windows Admin running it a sysadmin:

```
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -Q "if not exists(select * from sys.server_principals where name='BUILTIN\administrators') CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\administrators] FROM WINDOWS;EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'" 
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver 
sqlcmd -Q "if exists( select * from fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER') where permission_name = 'CONTROL SERVER') print 'You are a sysadmin.'"
```

Or you could modify it to allow a Windows Admin to change the user's password

```
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver /mSQLCMD 
sqlcmd -Q "alter login SomeLogin with password = '*********'" 
net stop mssqlserver 
net start mssqlserver
```

Comment: Why are you using `sp_addsrvrolemember` here? That been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2012 (might even be 2008 or prior).

Comment: Because I wrote the script in 2010, and so it works on older versions.